# How to set Emacs settings dependent upon GUI usage?

Tags: emacs

For whatever reason, when I press `backspace` in emacs (terminal version) it deletes the character before the cursor but the same key press in the emacs GUI (for Mac) deletes the character under the cursor. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of how to set `normal-erase-is-backspace-mode` dependent upon whether the emacs session is in the GUI or not?

For the record, according to `C-h k`, the `backspace` key is bound to `DEL` in both cases.

Comment: what is bound to `backspace` in both cases.? `C-h k` (please add that detail in your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the following in my emacs config under Mac to make backspace work fine:

```
;; Fix Delete key and activate graphical frame.
(defun my-make-frame-hook ()
  (when (window-system)
    (normal-erase-is-backspace-mode t)
    (when (fboundp 'ns-do-applescript)
      (ns-do-applescript "tell application \"Emacs\" to activate"))))

;; Do this for initial frame...
(my-make-frame-hook)

;; ...and for any subsequently created frame.
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          '(lambda (frame)
             (select-frame frame)
             (my-make-frame-hook)))
```

This solution is robust enough to work flawlessly even if you're using daemon mode.

(The ns-do-applescript is to raise new frames, obviously.)

The `(window-system)` should be of special interest to you here.

Comment: `(window-system)` does look interesting, yes. I shall remember it for next time. Thanks!

Comment: Check that, I like this now! Protection from surprises in daemon mode could be helpful to Me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function [`display-graphic-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Feature-Testing.html) will return `t` if emacs is using the windowing system, or `nil` if it's a terminal session.  You could do something like this:

```
(setq normal-erase-is-backspace (display-graphic-p))
```

Comment: There's one problem with similar approach though. If you start emacs in daemon mode, it won't use windowing system. But then you can use emacsclient to create a new frame that will use that already configured daemon, and windowing system. Which is why I originally had to add a hook to after-make-frame-functions.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Emacs are you using?  It seems very fishy that you should have to configure anything for backspace to work.

Start with

```
emacs -Q
```

and describe how backspace works.

Comment: I assure you that when you're using Cocoa UI of stock Emacs even in version 23.4, you need to manually configure backspace using normal-erase-is-backspace. I haven't tried removing that piece of config on v24 though.